# Responsive Email: Distribute three tables within a TD

Tags: responsive-design, html-email, css, text-align

I'm learning Responsive Email design and I've run into a snag when placing three tables into a td. I can place two tables into the td and align them left and right, respectively, and they lay out just fine. But when I throw in the third table, even after ensuring that total width of the three tables is markedly less than the width of the container table, they won't justify.

I've tried setting the td align="justify" and then aligning each table left:

```
      <tr>
        <td align="justify" valign="top" class="icons" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:24px;">
                <table class="gear" width="180" height="185" align="left" border="0" bgcolor="#00adef" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="gear" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    CLASSIC SOHO OFFICE. STATE OF THE ART INFRASTRUCTURE.<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/gear.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="arrow" width="180" height="185" align="left" border="0" bgcolor="#44c9f6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="arrow" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    CEILING UP TO 13'6", NATURAL LIGHT, OVERSIZE TERRACES<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/arrow.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="divide" width="180" height="185" align="left" border="0" bgcolor="#00b9f2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="divide" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    SPACES FROM<br/>11,000 TO 130,000 RSF<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/divide.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <br style="clear:both;">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I've tried excluding a td align property and simply aligning each of the tables to left, center, and right respectively:

```
     <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="icons" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:24px;">
                <table class="gear" width="180" height="185" align="left" border="0" bgcolor="#00adef" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="gear" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    CLASSIC SOHO OFFICE. STATE OF THE ART INFRASTRUCTURE.<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/gear.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="arrow" width="180" height="185" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#44c9f6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="arrow" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    CEILING UP TO 13'6", NATURAL LIGHT, OVERSIZE TERRACES<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/arrow.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="divide" width="180" height="185" align="right" border="0" bgcolor="#00b9f2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="divide" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    SPACES FROM<br/>11,000 TO 130,000 RSF<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/divide.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <br style="clear:both;">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I can't get anything to work. I'd really appreciate any help!

Here's a link to what I'm working on: http://michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/OSS20140918.html

-MC

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I added a master table with three columns and placed each smaller table into a column. I still have to go back and clean it all up, but it functions properly. Now to see if I can make it responsive.

```
      <tr>
        <td align="justify" valign="top" class="icons" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:24px;">
          <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table class="gear" align="left" width="185" height="185" border="0" bgcolor="#00adef" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="gear" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    CLASSIC SOHO OFFICE. STATE OF THE ART INFRASTRUCTURE.<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/gear.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table class="arrow" align="center" width="185" height="185" border="0" bgcolor="#44c9f6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="arrow" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    CEILING UP TO 13'6", NATURAL LIGHT, OVERSIZE TERRACES<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/arrow.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table class="divide" align="right" width="185" height="185" border="0" bgcolor="#00b9f2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="divide" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                    SPACES FROM<br/>11,000 TO 130,000 RSF<br/><br/><img src="http://www.michaelcoleman.net/files/cushman/20140918/images/divide.png" alt="One Soho Square" width="60" height="60" border="0px"></img>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```